# Displaying Character-Based Languages in Android?

Tags: java, android, character

I need to display a message in Korean for all of the Korean users of my Android app. It occurs to me that since Korean is a character-based language, it can't be displayed in any means using the English keyboard.

How exactly would I work with character-based languages and Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm ... last time I checked, you don't display messages on a keyboard :-)

Seriously, the Java / Android platform will cope *just fine* with character-based languages.  Java Strings are sequences of Unicode characters.  If there is a need to *enter* Korean characters, the platform should provide the means to do this, and wouldn't expect any problems with displaying them.

---

Ah ... so you mean character entry, not character display!

It turns out that there are a lot of [Android apps](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/korean%20text%20input) for this kind of thing.  You should probably download and use one of those ... and recommend to your Korean users to do likewise, if they don't have one installed by default by their mobile phone vendor.

Comment: I meant more that I can't figure out how exactly to type using my keyboard into Korean. And are there Unicode characters for Korean? I was unaware, but I'll look into it. Thanks.